# Crytal Report is not showing data in some fields

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am generating a report using crystal report of purchases Date Wise and with stock id.

I am using the stored procedure which is working fine and return all the data date wise, but in report the gross and total field is not showing data.

It shows just ####.

Comment: Field is designed too short :) Make it wider. You could make it display partial data, but IMO this behavior is worse.

Comment: Typical Rookie question!